# How to change time field in PDF while opening in user's machine?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to send a PDF file via email attachment in Outlook. There is field in PDF related to local time and the requirement is when PDF is open in user's system then time will show according to user's time zone. I created PDF using iText Sharp in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change data in a PDF when the user loads the document.

You could instead put a URL link in your email, then when the link is clicked the response is to create the PDF with the correct date. Don't know if that is possible within your system.

Comment: Thanks for your response!!!
But i can't go with that because I need to update time zone of pdf document when user open it.

Comment: Maybe the initial link should go to a page which is just a brief javascript function that gets the local date from the browser and then makes a call to the server including the local date, the server can then take this parameter and pass it into the function that creates the PDF?

Comment: Actually I have only email address of user and nothing else. I don't have any external interface for getting user's timezone. I need to do with only pdf.

Comment: Well then your constraints will prevent you from doing what you need to do. PDFs aren't functionally changeable like that. I would suggest listing all the options of timezones. Or if you must you'll have to build some other program which edits the pdf that the user would run first. This seems worse however.